# Galileo Positioning System signal receiving

Tags: gps

I want to determine my arduino's position. However, I want to use the *European* **Galileo** system instead of the *US-American GPS*.

Therefore, I searched for any possibilities receiving the Galileo signals. I figured out, that u-blox has some receivers: NEO 8 or the LEA 6 (firmware update required). However I did not find any arduino breakout board (, etc.) that uses these u-blox sensors or other Galileo-compatible hardware.

Does anyone know, how I could use the Galileo Position System?

Comment: First check that there is coverage in the area you want to use it. Currently coverage is mainly Europe. They are still in the process of putting more satellites into orbit.

Comment: but why using a system starting in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

You need the hardware and a library. Most GPS modules use a serial communication, and I think that also the Galileo compatible boards use serial communication. That makes them compatible with most microcontrollers and also with Arduino boards.

I could find a few shields that can be attached to an Arduino board.
This one is in development at the moment: [Kickstarter shield with Galileo](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sodaq/the-first-nb-iot-shield-for-arduino-supported-by-t)
This one is compatible via the serial pins: [GA-001 Multi GNSS Ublox](https://www.tindie.com/products/jrobi772/ga-001-multi-gnss-ublox-development-module/)
There is a "[NEO-M8N](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEO-M8N-GPS-Shield-for-Arduino-Indoor-Positioning-GPS-Galileo-GLONASS-BeiDou-/272086464137)" shield and maybe one or two others.

All those boards are very new, and I don't know if they come with a library for an Arduino. Perhaps you have to wait a few months and then it should be a lot easier to buy a complete functioning module with a library.

Before buying a module, confirm that there is a library for Arduino or good documentation to write your own library.

Comment: [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) is the only Arduino library that will work with the newest GPS devices, like the NEO-M8.